# Symmetric and Skew Symmetric Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

$V_0=$ the set of $2\times2$ skew symmetric matrices

I know that any element of $V_0$ has a characteristic polynomial that will not factor over the real numbers, and therefore has no eigenvectors.  Why is this so?  How would I go about showing this?

Comment: Technically, the $0$ matrix is a skew symmetric matrix that defies this statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way of getting there:

Let $A$ be a real, skew-symmetric matrix. Let $\lambda$ be a real eigenvalue of $A$, and $v$ an associated eigenvector.  We then note that
$$
\lambda(v \cdot v) = (\lambda v) \cdot v = (Av) \cdot v 
\\= v^T (Av) = v^T A v = -v^T A^T v = -(Av)^T v \\
= v\cdot (-Av) = v\cdot(-\lambda v) = -\lambda (v \cdot v)
$$
So, if $\lambda$ is a real eigenvalue, we have $\lambda \|v\|^2 = -\lambda \|v\|^2$, which (since $v$ is by definition non-zero) implies that $\lambda = 0$.

So, if $A$ is skew-symmetric, the only eigenvalue it can have is $0$.

Comment: This is of course the morally right approach, the one that ignores the superfluous restriction to $2\times2$ matrices; +1. But I would be tempted to shorten this using $(Av)\cdot v=v\cdot(A^Tv)$ (as that is what matrix transposition is about for me), but maybe there are pedagogical reasons to avoid that? (Also note that you meant $v$ instead of $x$ in your introduction.)

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen *pedagogical reasons* is right; I'm not sure the asker ever learned such a justification for transposition, so I can imagine that a quick switch like this might look like magic.  And thanks for the note.

Answer (score 6):

Let us examine the chacteristic polynomial $p_S(\lambda)$ of $S$, a skew-symmetric $2 \times 2$ matrix.  As is well-known, and in fact easily derived, we have

$p_S(\lambda) = \lambda^2 - \text{Tr}(S)\lambda + \det (S). \tag{1}$

Writing

$S = [s_{ij}], \tag{2}$

we see that the skew-symmetry of $S$ implies the diagonal entries $s_{ii} = 0$,
since $S^T = -S$ implies $s_{ii} =-s_{ii}$ for $i = 1,2$.  Thus the trace of $S$ vanishes, and furthermore we have

$\det(S) = -s_{12}s_{21} = s_{12}^2 >0 \tag{3}$

if $S \ne 0$.  Thus

$p_S(\lambda) = \lambda^2 + s_{12}^2; \tag{4}$

but the roots of (4) are $\pm i\vert s_{12} \vert$, both purely imaginary, so $p_A(\lambda)$ is irreducuble over $\Bbb R$.

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: I was wondering where you signature sign-off was :) Always a fan of your contributions here!

Comment: @Omnomnomnom:  Sometimes I add it after first posting if I feel like I am in a "race"; I'm sure you know what I mean!  And thanks so much for the good words!  I *really* appreciate them, especially from a professional such as yourself!  Best Regards!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A = \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}$ is skew-symmetric. Then, $A+A^T = \begin{bmatrix}2a&b+c\\b+c&2d\end{bmatrix} = 0$.

What does this tell you about $a,b,c,d$? This lets you write $A$ in terms of just $b$.

From there, it should be easy to show that $A$ has no real eigenvalues.

Answer (score 1):

The set of real skew-symmetric $2\times 2$ matrices is a $1$-dimensional real vector space. Given that if a matrix is diagonalisable, so are all its scalar multiples (with the same eigenvectors, and eigenvalues multiplied by the scalar in question), it suffices to test the condition for a single nonzero real skew-symmetric $2\times 2$ matrix. Choosing $(\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\-1&0\end{smallmatrix})$ for simplicity one sees its characteristic polynomial is $X^2+1$ and has no real roots: also the matrix represents a rotation by a quarter turn which clearly has no real eigenvalues (it fixes no lines).

Of course, as was commented, this only shows that *nonzero* real skew-symmetric $2\times 2$ matrices are not diagonalisable, and the zero matrix *is* of course diagonalisable.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ is a $2 \times2$ skew symmetric metric, then $A$ has the form $$A = \begin{bmatrix}0&a\\-a&0\end{bmatrix}$$ 
Supose $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ are  the eigen values of $A.$
Then $tr(A)=\lambda_1+\lambda_2=0,$ and $det(A)=\lambda_1\lambda_2=a^2.$
Clearly the eigen values are $\lambda_1=ia$ and $\lambda_2=-ia.$
Therefor no non zero real vectors $v$ such that $$Av= \lambda v$$ for real $a \not =0. $